# Refresh Birt Report

Tags: birt

I want to refresh my BIRT report automatically. Report is deployed on tomcat 5.x server. How can I do it ? Is there any parameter setting ?

Thanks,
Sampath

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, this write-up does exactly what you need.

[Reusable Library for report refresh](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/714-reusable-library-for-reloading-a-report/#description)

Good Luck!

Comment: your link is outdated. Can you recap the conclusion of the linked source?